# Can Not Send Notification to iOS (iPhone) Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In `Info.plist`, I have added `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO (boolean)`, and capabilities for `Background Modes --> Remote Notification` is ON and `Push Notification` is ON too.

And on the iPhone device, has running with dialog to "allow notification"..

I have some codes like:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    let gcmBroadcast = "gcm.broadcast"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        // Use Firebase library to configure APIs

        let firebasePListFileName = ControllerEnvironment.getGoogleService()

        let firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: firebasePListFileName, ofType: "plist")!)

        FirebaseApp.configure(options: firebaseOptions!)



//        firebase cloud messaging

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self



            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(

                options: authOptions,

                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        } else {

            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =

                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)

            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        }


        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true

    }



    // [START receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,

        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics

         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmBroadcast] {

            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],

                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,

        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics

         Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmBroadcast] {

            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    }

    // [END receive_message]

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }


    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.

    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to

    // the FCM registration token.

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.

         Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    }

}







// [START ios_10_message_handling]

@available(iOS 10, *)

extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,

                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,

                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo


        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics

        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmBroadcast] {

            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }


        // Print full message.

        print(userInfo)



        // Change this to your preferred presentation option

        completionHandler([])

    }


    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,

                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,

                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        // Print message ID.

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmBroadcast] {

            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")

        }


        // Print full message.

        print(userInfo)


        completionHandler()

    }

}

// [END ios_10_message_handling]


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    // [START refresh_token]

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")


        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.

        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.

    }

    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START ios_10_data_message]

    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.

    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {

        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")

    }

    // [END ios_10_data_message]

}
```

and logs:

```
Firebase registration token: f6MUKT270iw:APA9.......Eg
APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
```

I tried sending Push using firebase cloud messaging console as: `User segment -> app` and got status **completed** in firebase list of messages.

But, actually my iPhone did not receive the notification.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Have you setup Key or push certiciate.p12 in Project settings?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS the app needs to be not in foreground, as otherwise the developer is informed of the push notification and can manually display it / handle it otherwise -> make sure that the app is not in the foreground

You also need to add an APNs key or APNs certificates to Firebase.

Comment: Ohhh yeahhh,,, You are right, My app in foreground + I did not upload the key... Thank you,...

Comment: This currently reads like a comment instead of an answer. It might be better to change the wording here.